# How do I fix this error - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemon

I'm working on a project with some friends and wanting to start a project with `npm run development` I get this error:

```
    const requireSignin = Object(express_jwt__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["expressJwt"])({
                                                                                    ^

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Module.eval (webpack:///./server/controllers/auth.controller.js?:58:85)
    at eval (webpack:///./server/controllers/auth.controller.js?:95:30)
    at Module../server/controllers/auth.controller.js (/Users/mihailomitrovic/Downloads/iteh_projekat/dist/server.generated.js:420:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/mihailomitrovic/Downloads/iteh_projekat/dist/server.generated.js:21:30)
    at Module.eval (webpack:///./server/routes/user.routes.js?:5:86)
    at eval (webpack:///./server/routes/user.routes.js?:36:30)
    at Module../server/routes/user.routes.js (/Users/mihailomitrovic/Downloads/iteh_projekat/dist/server.generated.js:540:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/mihailomitrovic/Downloads/iteh_projekat/dist/server.generated.js:21:30)
    at Module.eval (webpack:///./server/express.js?:17:77)
    at eval (webpack:///./server/express.js?:165:30)
    at Module../server/express.js (/Users/mihailomitrovic/Downloads/iteh_projekat/dist/server.generated.js:468:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/mihailomitrovic/Downloads/iteh_projekat/dist/server.generated.js:21:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./server/server.js?:3:66)
    at Module../server/server.js (/Users/mihailomitrovic/Downloads/iteh_projekat/dist/server.generated.js:552:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/mihailomitrovic/Downloads/iteh_projekat/dist/server.generated.js:21:30)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_./server/server.js?:1:18)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I've tried looking for solutions and looking at parts of the code but nothing has helped so far. Does it have something to do with importing a module? Can someone please help or at least point me in the right direction?

Since it's referring me to this file, this is the code from `auth.controller.js`:

```
import User from '../models/user.model'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import { expressJwt } from 'express-jwt'
import config from './../../config/config'

const signin = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({
      "email": req.body.email
    })
    if (!user)
      return res.status('401').json({
        error: "User not found"
      })

    if (!user.authenticate(req.body.password)) {
      return res.status('401').send({
        error: "Email and password don't match."
      })
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({
      _id: user._id
    }, config.jwtSecret)

    res.cookie("t", token, {
      expire: new Date() + 9999
    })

    return res.json({
      token,
      user: {
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email
      }
    })

  } catch (err) {

    return res.status('401').json({
      error: "Could not sign in"
    })

  }
}

const signout = (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie("t")
  return res.status('200').json({
    message: "signed out"
  })
}

const requireSignin = expressJwt({
  secret: config.jwtSecret,
  userProperty: 'auth'
})

const hasAuthorization = (req, res, next) => {
  const authorized = req.profile && req.auth && req.profile._id == req.auth._id
  if (!(authorized)) {
    return res.status('403').json({
      error: "User is not authorized"
    })
  }
  next()
}

export default {
  signin,
  signout,
  requireSignin,
  hasAuthorization
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have some issues importing a module. Please share the code of `auth.controller.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by importing `express-jwt`.

You need to replace it with this:

```ts
import { expressjwt } from 'express-jwt'
```

and you need to pass `algorithms` as an option when invoking `expressjwt`:

```
expressjwt({
  secret: config.jwtSecret,
  userProperty: 'auth', // and what is this? I'm not sure 'express-jwt' accepts this option
  algorithms: ["HS256"]
})
```

You may need to read the doc on how to use [express-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt).

Comment: Now I'm getting the error that Object(...) is not a function and the rest of the code is the same

Comment: The error you mentioned in your question was related to the wrong importing. If you have another error and you are sure it's related to this question, please update the question and attach the newest error(at least 3-4 lines of error would be helpful). I cannot update my answer with this vague short error: `Object(...) is not a function`

Comment: I've updated the question with the changed code and the new error I'm getting, thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer, and I had a typo, that should be `expressjwt` not `expressJwt`.